# MacOS code signature issue with pandoc/lpeg

Tags: pandoc, quarto, lpeg

I am trying to run quarto preview on a .qmd file.

I get this error:

```
error loading module 'lpeg' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so':
        dlopen(/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so, 0x0006): tried: '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' (code signature in <6BE10D0F-FF8F-38A3-A602-15DE5DB932C7> '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' (code signature in <6BE10D0F-FF8F-38A3-A602-15DE5DB932C7> '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.)
```

I have tried the following:

- updating and reinstall pandoc and lpeg with homebrew
- removing pandoc and lpeg and reinstalling with other methods (.pkg for pandoc and luarocks for lpeg)
- ad-hoc signing lpeg.so

After ad-hoc signing lpeg.so I get this error:

```
 '/usr/local/Cellar/lpeg/1.1.0/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' not valid for use in proce
ss: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs)
```

here is some more detail from the system logs:

```
 Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleMobileFileIntegrity) Library Validation failed: Rejecting '/usr/local/Cellar/lpeg/1.1.0/lib/lua/5.4/lpeg.so' (Team ID: none, platform: no) for process 'pandoc(15130)' (Team ID: FYF2F5GFX4, platform: no), reason: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs
```

Versions:

Pandoc:

```
pandoc 3.1.12.3
Features: +server +lua
Scripting engine: Lua 5.4
```

Quarto version is 1.4.551

OS is Sonoma 14.2.1

Xcode details:

```
Xcode 15.3
Build version 15E204a
```

Comment: I'd suggest reporting this to homebrew. Is lpeg a dependency of pandoc in homebrew? The cask should already have it compiled-in, I think.